# Place key file in APK

Tags: android

Trying to build application apk file by using gradle, task `assemble`. My application contains private key file and I got error:

```
E:\D\android\MQTT\app\src\main\res\raw\clientkey.pem: Error: The raw\\clientkey.pem file seems to be a private key file. Please make sure not to embed this in your APK file. [PackagedPrivateKey]

   Explanation for issues of type "PackagedPrivateKey":
   In general, you should not package private key files inside your app. 

1 errors, 0 warnings

> Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

  To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          checkReleaseBuilds false
          // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
          // but continue the build even when errors are found:
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
```

I know it is not secure to keep key in apk, but currently I would like to place it in apk. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

This check can be disabled per file; module `build.gradle`:

```
lintOptions {
    lintConfig file("../lint.xml")
}
```

Root project `lint.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="PackagedPrivateKey">
        <ignore path="src/main/res/raw/clientkey.pem"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Disclaimer: Please be aware, that the private key could be leaked alike this.